# Error during failsafe response when raising an exception in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

In my API I use Rails' `exceptions_app` to handle all exceptions and make a standard JSON response. This works fine except when I raise an exception in the `ApplicationController`. The controller looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :raise_exception
  def raise_exception
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
end
```

When I request any page I would expect to get a 404 status response. Instead of this Rails returns a 500 status. The log shows this error message:

```
Error during failsafe response: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

What does this mean and how can I work around it?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

In your config/application.rb, see if the line below is commented out.  If it isn't, comment it out and see if the error still persist.

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```